# If/elif/else statement - can't seem to get the desired output

Tags: python-3.x

If input_month = "jan" the script works properly, but if input_month = any other month, it doesn't seem to perform any of the elif blocks and goes straight to else and pass.

(This is using the openpyxl module to load/write to an excel file, not sure if I needed to mention that)

*Also, is there any way to refactor that into something neater?  I'm not an experienced programmer but I feel like this is not the best way to perform this.*

```
if x in reporting:
    wb = load_workbook('report.xlsx')
    ws = wb[f'Rep{x}']

    wb['Summary']['B3'] = month_year

    ws['C5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][1]
    ws['D5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][3]
    ws['E5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][2]
    ws['C6'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][0]
    ws['C6'].number_format = '#,##0.00'

    if (input_month == "jan"):
        ws['C22'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #january
        ws['C22'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "feb"):
        ws['C23'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #february
        ws['C23'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "mar"):
        ws['C24'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #march
        ws['C24'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "apr"):
        ws['C25'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #april
        ws['C25'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "may"):
        ws['C26'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #may
        ws['C26'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "jun"):
        ws['C27'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #june
        ws['C27'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "jul"):
        ws['C28'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #july
        ws['C28'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "aug"):
        ws['C29'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #august
        ws['C29'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "sep"):
        ws['C30'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #september
        ws['C30'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "oct"):
        ws['C31'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #october
        ws['C31'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "nov"):
        ws['C32'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #november
        ws['C32'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    elif (input_month == "dec"):
        ws['C33'] = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"] #december
        ws['C33'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    else:
        pass

    wb.save('Sales Analysis ' + month_year + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Can you add/show explicitly a stand alone example of the part of your code, which is not working as expected, which not depends on some files, that only you have? Often trying to compile such examples helps you find the error, and if not, the resulting example helps others to help you solving your issue :)

Comment: Use dictionary with `month` as keys and `ws[ ]` as values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ideas!

I was able to get it working with a dict; I read up on case/switch statements in python and tried to build a function which got 90% there but kept getting an iterate error that I'll continue to try and debug.

The missing detail seemed to be ".value"

I tried to do the same thing for the .number_format but the following code didn't work:

```
report_dict[input_month].value.number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

The following is what is working right now:

```
wb = load_workbook('report.xlsx')
wb['Summary']['B3'] = month_year

for x in repnumbers:
    if x in reporting:
        ws = wb[f'Rep{x}']
        ws['C5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][1]
        ws['D5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][3]
        ws['E5'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][2]
        ws['C6'] = terr_dets[f'Rep{x}'][0]
        ws['C6'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        report_dict = {"jan": ws['C22'],
                "feb": ws['C23'],
                "mar": ws['C24'],
                "apr": ws['C25'],
                "may": ws['C26'],
                "jun": ws['C27'],
                "jul": ws['C28'],
                "aug": ws['C29'],
                "sep": ws['C30'],
                "oct": ws['C31'],
                "nov": ws['C32'],
                "dec": ws['C33']
        } 
        report_dict[input_month].value = totals_rep_dict[f"totals_rep{x}"]
        # report_dict[input_month].value.number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C22'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C23'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C24'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C25'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C26'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C27'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C28'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C29'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C30'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C31'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C32'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        ws['C33'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
        wb.save('Sales Analysis ' + month_year + '.xlsx')
```